# Are there any Sound classes similar to the s:ContentCache?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

Is there a ContentCache[1] for sound assets? Once I load in a sound I want to keep a reference to it so it doesn't have to load again. Possibly a class reference to it or to the byte array (I'm rusty here).

The reason for this is to keep it in memory so the Flash Player doesn't have to reload it so the start time (latency) is low. These are short audio clips.

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/ContentCache.html

Comment: No. CacheContent use Loader and it can not load sound file.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the sound files are larger than what the cache permits, they should be cached internally.

I think you should download and save the file yourself otherwise.

Comment: Cached by the Flash Player / AIR?

Comment: Unless the behaviour has changed, in the case of FP the content is cached in the browser's cache. For AIR, URLRequest provides a cacheResponse property which uses, per documentation, "the operating system's HTTP cache", which I guess that for Windows machines, it's the same place where IE stores its cache as well.